# how to custom UITableViewCell with xib file autolayout width

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

i'm trying to custom UITableViewCell with xib file, i'm using AutoLayout but it's not working. how i can fixed? i tryed to search in google but no answer for me.
[image]

update my code ---- 
[image]

Comment: how we can recognize the issue by this image. so add your work done code.

Comment: as @dahiya_boy stated, give us some code because their could be a lot of different things causing your "problem" -- which i'm not sure what your problem is here.  If you are wanting your cells to be full width, pin your `tableView` to be 0 points from the `leading` and `trailing` of its ViewController

Comment: @dahiya_boy please lookat my update

Comment: @JacobBoyd because in storyboard too hard for upload code. Please check my edited

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the `autolayout` on your contentView of `UITableViewCell`. Only set inside the attributes (like SubView, imageView, label etc). You can add the subView inside your content View and apply the constraint there and make your ContentView transparent. In order to achieve your styling.

Comment: i only set autolayout for all view inside contentView. But UITableViewCell only autofix size for width of contentView in xib file (300).